# Запятые между частями сложного предложения, связанными подчинительной связью

Tags: синтаксический-разбор, сложное-предложение

В приведённых ниже предложениях из прочитанного текста пронумерованы все запятые. Выпишите цифры, обозначающие запятые между частями сложного предложения, связанными подчинительной связью.

– Спасибо,(1) – сказал Назаров,(2) – но я не за этим приехал. У меня болен отец. Мы приехали в Москву,(3) но в Москве я знаю только Вас,(4) и я хотел спросить,(5) можем ли мы остановиться у Вас на неделю?
–  Нет,(6) нет,(7) – поспешно сказала Сергеева. – Это неудобно,(8) потому что у меня совсем маленькая квартира.

Я точно понимаю, что **8** подходит. Меня смущает формулировка вопроса:
"Выпишите цифр**ы**". Неужели **5** подходит как ответ на вопрос? Ведь там нет союзной связи.

Comment: Задание из КИМов ГИА. Я бы особенно не обращала внимания на число существительного. И хоть в данном случае здесь действительно "цифры", даже в экзаменационных материалах (в отличие от КИМов ЕГЭ), бывает так, что написано "выпишите предложение", а на самом деле их два, и наоборот. Поэтому смотрите и анализируйте внимательно весь предложенный материал.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Там есть союзная связь.  "Ли" в придаточном изъяснительном выполняет функцию подчинительного союза.

Comment: Спасибо, как раз над "ли" я и сомневался.